# Use of "ganz" instead of "alle/all"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adjective

Here is an excerpt from my German grammar book on the usage of the adjective "ganz"
[image]

I have a couple of clarifications to make. First, why is "ganze" used in Nominativ and not "ganz"? Second, why is it "*den ganzen* Tag" and not "*der ganze* Tag"? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. Are you asking about the declination of "ganz", why "ganz" is used instead of "alle", or both?

Answer (score 2):

That's all just the declination of "ganz". It is declined like an adjective.

See e.g. the entry for ["ganze"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ganze) in Wiktionary: here it is used because "Familie" is a feminine noun (*die Familie*), and "die ganze Familie" is in nominative in the example.

The example "den [ganzen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ganzen) Tag" is in accusative because that is what is used in a German sentence when describing a time span adverbially. The accusative makes clear that "den ganzen Tag" is not the subject of the sentence, but denotes the time span of the action.

> Die Kinder spielten den ganzen Tag (lang) im Garten.
> The kids played in the garden all day (long).

As a subject, it would be different in both German and English:

> Der ganze Tag war sonnig und warm.
> The whole day was sunny and warm.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 5th line, "ganz" is an adjective like any other, so takes the same endings as any other adjective.

Before a proper noun referring to a location without an article, you use "ganz" undeclined, that is what is happening in the 4th example.

For "den ganzen" vs. "der ganze", the explanation given in [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73984/54754) is correct.

Difference between "ganz" and "alle": "ganz" = entire, all of, all parts of the thing that follows; "alle" = all, all elements of the grouping that follows.

- Die ganze Familie kommt. = The entire family is coming.
- Alle Familien kommen. = All families are coming.